# AngularJS http interceptors responseError never called with IE9

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-9, angular-promise, angularjs-http

I'm confronted with a problem with `$http.get` configured with a timeout with IE9 only. When the request is aborted, my http interceptor is never called.

Has anyone else also confronted this problem?

Here is my http interceptor code:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('core.httpInterceptor', [
        'core'
    ], ['$provide', function($provide) {
        $provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor',
            ['$rootScope', '$q',
                function(scope, $q) {

                    return {
                        request: function(config) {
                            // BUSINESS CODE

                            return config || $q.when(config);
                        },
                        response: function(response) {
                            // BUSINESS CODE

                            return response || $q.when(response);
                        },
                        responseError: function(rejection) {
                            // NEVER CALLED WHEN ABORTED !
                            // BUSINESS CODE

                            return $q.reject(rejection);
                        }
                    };
                }]);
    }]);
}());
```

The `$http` request code:

```
$http.get(API_URL, {timeout: 5000})
    .then(function(response) {
        // BUSINESS LOGIC
    }, function() {
        // BUSINESS LOGIC
    });
```

The strange thing is that with other status codes (400 for example) the interceptor is working like expected.

AngularJS version is: 1.4.8.

This problem happens only with IE9. With IE10+, Chrome, Firefox, everything is working like a charm.